# Rails : simple_format is rendering html tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a string that looks like this:

```
 <p><%= truncate(event.description, length: 450) %></p>
```

Here's what renders in the html:

```
"Pacific North West Fall Time Paint & Sip Pint Night7:00-9:30pm

It's that time of year for fall leaves, hoodies, pumpkins and s'mores and for our new Fall-themed Painting. Artist Iris Mes Low is developing a Fall-themed painting that will capture the beauty of the Pacific North West.  You'll be able to enjoy a glass of wine or beer & light appies while painting your very own masterpiece.  We provide all the paint supplies and our artist take..."
```

Except my view is rendering it all in one long string. I'd like to render it with the correct spacing like it shows in above HTML.

I tried:

```
<p><%= truncate(simple_format(event.description, {}, :sanitize => false), length: 450) %></p>
```

But this renders the text *with* the actual html tags:

```
<p>Pacific North West Fall Time Paint & Sip Pint Night7:00-9:30pm</p> <p>It's that time of year for fall leaves, hoodies, pumpkins and s'mores and for our new Fall-themed Painting. Artist Iris Mes Low is developing a Fall-themed painting that will capture the beauty of the Pacific North West.  You'll be able to enjoy a glass of wine or beer & light appies while painting your very own masterpiece.  We provide all the paint supplies and our art...
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: try using `event.description.html_safe`, it might convert the `\n` to HTML newlines (br), but not sure about this

Comment: Yeah this has no impact from the original event.description

Comment: What about `strip_tags` ? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-strip_tags

Comment: undefined method strip_tags for "string". What's the full line supposed to look like?

Comment: @MrYoshiji ... html_safe does not make the string html safe ... it flags it as being html safe - meaning, it won't attempt to html escape any characters in the string.

Comment: have you tried <pre> tag...<pre><%= truncate(simple_format(event.description, {}, :sanitize => false), length: 450) %></pre>

Comment: @BalaKarthik That is also outputting tags like "<br />"

Comment: @JacksonCunningham try this one `<p><%= simple_format(truncate(event.description), length: 450) %></p>`

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but this should solve your problem.

```
  <p><%= simple_format(truncate(event.description, {}, :sanitize => false, length: 450)) %></p>
```